# Coloring the uncountable Lebesgue-measurable sets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, infinite-combinatorics, hypergraph, lebesgue-measure

A *hypergraph* $H=(V,E)$ consists of a set $V$ and $E\subseteq {\mathcal P}(V)$, that is, $E$  consists of subsets of $V$ of arbitrary size. Obviously, a graph is a special kind of hypergraph.

Let $H=(V,E)$ be a hypergraph and  $\kappa\neq \emptyset$ be a cardinal.
Then a map $c:V\to \kappa$ is said to be a *coloring* if for every $e\in E$ with $|e|\geq 2$ we have that the restriction $c\restriction_e$ is non-constant. The *chromatic
number* $\chi(H)$ of $H$ is the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such there is a colouring $c:V\to \kappa$.

**Question.** What is $\chi(\mathbb{R}, E)$ where $E$ consists of all uncountable Lebesgue-measurable sets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is continuum. The coloring with continuum many colors is clear (all points may have different color). Assume that we have $\kappa<c$ colors. Consider the Cantor set $K$. All its subsets are Lebesgue measurable. If some color contains uncountably many points from $K$, it constitutes a monochromatic edge. So, each color contains at most $\omega$ points from $K$, and totally $|K|\leqslant w\cdot \kappa=\kappa$, a contradiction.

Comment: What if one removes the measure-$0$ sets?

Comment: @LSpice then it changes dramatically: it is 2. Take a Hamel basis over $\mathbb{Q}$, denote by $f(x)$ a coordinate functional and use two colors: $\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$ is even or odd.

Comment: Cool subquestion @LSpice and impressively quick answer Fedor!!